# Need to remove plates in function in python

Tags: python, stack

Parameters: Remove a given number of plates from the top of the stack. The value should be a positive integer. If the value is less than or equal to zero, reject the operation and issue a warning.

If there are too many plates selected, reject the operation and issue a warning. Otherwise, remove plates from the stack and print a message.

This is the function I created:

```
def remove_plates():
    print(" ")
    print("Remove plates") 
    print("=========")   
    size = read_int("How many plates would you like removed?: ")
    for index, size in enumerate(plates):

        if size <= (index + 1):
            plates.remove(size)
            print(f"{size} removed, success!")
        elif size <= 0:
            print(f"Error: {size} plates cannot be removed from the stack.")
        elif size >= (index + 1):
            print(f"Error: {size} plates cannot be removed from the stack.")
        else:
            print(f"{size} removed, success!")

        print(" ")
```

I input the numbers 10 and 8 into a list and then asked the code to remove 4 items from the list.
I expected it to output: "4 plates cannot be removed from the stack." Instead it output:

Error: 10 plates cannot be removed from the stack.

Error: 8 plates cannot be removed from the stack.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. See [ask] for more information. From the question, you need to check that the number of plates remaining is greater than the number to be removed before your start removing plates.

Comment: Except for the error checking, this operation requires one statement: `plates = plates[size:]`.  No looping.

Answer (score 0):

The variable “size” that you assigned to the input is not the same object as the completely new variable “size” that was created in the for loop (and which constitutes the value in plates).

To be honest, you just need to compare the (input) size with len(plates), not enumerate anything.